# Combine multiple numeric values is one cell

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with my query to Combine multiple numeric values is one cell

This is the main table:

| Contact_ID | Order_id | Order_group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32221 | 122223 | 55555 |
| 32221 | 122224 | 55555 |
| 32221 | 122225 | 44444 |
| 32221 | 122226 | 44444 |
| 32221 | 122227 | 44444 |

My query:

```
 
SELECT
    Contact_ID,
    STRING_AGG( Order_group , ', ')  as 'ORDER GROUP'
FROM 
    Main 
 where Contact_ID = 32221 
GROUP BY Contact_ID
```

what I  get:

| Contact_ID | ORDER GROUP |
| --- | --- |
| 32221 | 55555,55555,44444,44444, no end... |

what I  need is similar to this:

| Contact_ID | ORDER GROUP |
| --- | --- |
| 32221 | 55555,44444 |

how i can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
    D.Contact_ID,
    STRING_AGG( D.Order_group , ', ')  as 'ORDER GROUP'
FROM 
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT Contact_ID, Order_group FROM  Main 
    ) D 
 where D.Contact_ID = 32221 
GROUP BY D.Contact_ID
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/49BLGdPn).

You may also specify the order of the list using `WITHIN GROUP` as the following:

```
STRING_AGG( D.Order_group , ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Order_group DESC) as 'ORDER GROUP'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a group by to the original set to build a distinct contactid and group order data set.

Then apply you string_agg to the outer query

```
SELECT
t2.Contact_ID
, STRING_AGG(t2.Order_group , ', ')  as 'ORDER GROUP'
FROM
(

SELECT
    Contact_ID
   , Order_group
   
FROM 
    Main 
 where Contact_ID = 32221 
GROUP BY Contact_ID , Order_group

) t2

GROUP BY t2.Contact_ID
```